# Does Devise cach authentication data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I ran into this weird situation here. I developed a JavaScript-based frontend for my Rails backend API.

I have a login form that posts username and password to my `TokensController` that returns the `authentication_token` stored in the database. This token is being stored in a cookie and submitted with every form.

Now I wanted to implement a logout function. So, I delete the cookie so no token gets submitted in a request. (Or a wrong one, in this case the header is `Authentication: Token token="undefined"`)

But still, the Rails backend returns `200 OK` with all the data, although the wrong token is defined. How is this possible? Is there any other session cache that is used to authenticate a request?

This is my super class that implements the authentication:

```
module Api
  class SecureBaseController < ApplicationController

    prepend_before_filter :get_auth_token
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    protected
    def get_auth_token
      puts token_value
      params[:auth_token] = token_value
    end

    def token_value
      if header && header =~ /^Token token="(.+)"$/
      $~[1]
      end
    end

    def header
      request.headers["Authorization"]
    end

  end
end
```

Even `puts` prints "undefined" in the console, as submitted by the web application, yet it authenticates the user correctly?

Comment: Why don't you logout the user using Ajax? DELETE "/users/sign_out" with Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"users-token"}

Comment: Yes, that would be quite failsafe. I thought, just not sending the right Authentication token would be some kind of log-out.

Comment: I'll have to do the same, but haven't started yet. I found this blog, that looks helpful: http://natashatherobot.com/devise-rails-sign-in/

Comment: Now I added `config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth, :token_auth]` to `config/initializers/devise.rb` and deactivated session routes. Wiped the database, restarted server and still I access the data although the token is wrong. What's going on here?

Comment: Okay now after AGAIN seeding the database and trying things out, this actually seemed to do the trick.